# django - display the human readable when running Avg()

Tags: python, django

I'm figuring out this piece by piece. I want users to be able to rate blog posts based on 4 criteria (difficulty_rating, workload_rating, book_rating, attendance_rating). I have used choices in my models.py to give users a choice.

After that, thanks to a user from StackOverflow, I was able to calculate the average for each of these values and display them at the top of every single post.

The problem is that they show up as floats with long decimals. Is there a way to show the human readable instead? Which comes from my model tuples?

I have done an {% if %} statement inside my template hardcoding everything, but I'm pretty sure there has to be a better way.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOISES = (

        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),

        )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    seo_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    seo_description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts', default=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=STATUS_CHOISES, default='draft')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.slug])


    def avg_ratings(self):
        return self.comments.aggregate(
            Avg('difficulty_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('workload_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('book_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('attendance_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
        )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Comment(models.Model):
    difficulty_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Very Easy'),
        (2, 'Easy'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Hard'),
        (5, 'Very Hard'),

    )

    workload_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Very Light'),
        (2, 'Light'),
        (3, 'Moderate'),
        (4, 'Heavy'),
        (5, 'Very Heavy'),

    )

    book_rating_choices = (

        (1, '$'),
        (2, '$$'),
        (3, '$$$'),
        (4, '$$$$'),
        (5, '$$$$$'),

    )

    attendance_rating_choices = (

        (1, 'Not Required'),
        (2, 'Required'),


    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    difficulty_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=difficulty_rating_choices)
    workload_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=workload_rating_choices)
    book_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=book_rating_choices)
    attendance_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=attendance_rating_choices)


    def approved(self):
        self.approved = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
template = 'blog/post/post_detail.html'
context = {

    'post': post,

}
return render(request, template, context)
```

template

```
{% with avg_ratings=post.avg_ratings %}
<h1>Difficulty: {{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating__avg }}</h1>
        <h1>Workload: {{ avg_ratings.workload_rating__avg }}<h1>
        <h1>Book Cost: {{ avg_ratings.book_rating__avg }}<h1>
        <h1>Attendance: {{ avg_ratings.attendance_rating__avg }}<h1>

    {% endwith %}
```

Comment: I am that stackoverflow user who solved your avg ratings issue :) tell me one thing lets say `difficulty_rating_choices` average is `2.5` would you want to display difficulty level as `Light` or `Moderate`? i think whatever you choose is unbiased.

Comment: >=0 and <=0.9 Very Easy, >=1 and <=1.9 Easy, >=2 and <=2.9 Moderate, >=3 and <=3.9 Hard, >=4 and <=5 Very Hard, that would be somewhat ideal, if not I'd like to be able to change it in the future if needed?

Comment: Wouldn't it makes more sense if you display it as range e.g. if avg rating for difficulty is 1.7 you would say "Very Easy to Easy"?

Comment: I haven't decided yet, it might make more sense sure. But I can decide on that later no? For now I still haven't figured out what's the best way to have "Easy" instead of "1.7".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a django template filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat

For example:

```
{{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating__avg|floatformat:"-3" }}
```

If by "human readable" you want to substitute words for ranges of values, create your own custom template filter to do that.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-writing-custom-template-filters

You could do something like (add the ranges for your levels):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def rating_humanize(value): # Only one argument.
    if value < 1.0:
        return 'Very Easy'
    elif value < 2.0:
        return 'Easy'
    else:
        return 'Hard'
```

A better implementation would be to make a list of range to string mappings and then find the matching range and return the string for it.

Comment: What I did so far is in my template, I have put {% if %} statements everywhere. So for example, if difficulty_rating is between 1 and 1.9, I have <p>Difficulty: Easy</p>. Which is a manual way of doing it. The problem with this is that it takes a lot of lines in my template. So I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. Would a custom template filter help?

Comment: I did just that and it works perfectly! thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `DecimalField(decimal_places=2)` instead of `FloatField` would help.

[Decimal docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield)

Comment: I ideally want text to output instead. So if for example difficulty_rating is between 1 and 1.9, I'd want it to say "Easy" instead of 1.7 for example. So far I have coded it manually with an {% if %} statement inside my template. If difficulty_rating >=1 and <= 1.9, output <p>Difficulty: Easy</p>. But as mentioned, this takes a lot of lines of code and I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the best solution but this what I came up with, you need to update `avg_ratings` method in your `Post` model:

```
import math

class Post(models.Model):
    # ...

    def avg_ratings(self):
        ratings = {}
        data = self.comments.aggregate(
            Avg('difficulty_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('workload_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('book_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
            Avg('attendance_rating', output_field=FloatField()),
        )

        for key, val in data.items():
            key = key.replace('__avg', '')
            scaled_val = int(math.ceil(val))
            display = ''
            choices = getattr(CommentTest, '{}_choices'.format(key))
            for choice_display, choice_val in choices:
                if scaled_val == choice_val:
                    display = choice_display
                    break
            if not display:
                raise Exception('Display for "{}" avg with value "{}" not found.'.format(key, scaled_val))
            ratings[key] = (scaled_val, display, val)
        return ratings
```

Then in template:

```
{% with avg_ratings=post.avg_ratings %}
  <h1>Difficulty: {{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating.0 }} - {{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating.1 }}</h1>
  <h1>Workload: {{ avg_ratings.workload_rating.0 }} - {{ avg_ratings.workload_rating.1 }}<h1>
  <h1>Book Cost: {{ avg_ratings.book_rating.0 }} - {{ avg_ratings.book_rating.1 }}<h1>
  <h1>Attendance: {{ avg_ratings.attendance_rating.0 }} - {{ avg_ratings.attendance_rating.1 }}<h1>
{% endwith %}
```

What `avg_ratings` method does is that it prepares dictionary of ratings in this format:

```
{'difficulty_rating': (2, 'Easy', 1.9), ..}
```

The value for each key will be a tuple containing three values:

- First value will be scaled value of avg e.g. if avg was 1.7 it will be considered as 2.
- Second value is the human readable display value.
- Third value is the actual avg value which was scaled.

I have used `math.ceil` in this logic but you can decide your own logic later as you said.

Comment: this works, but I think I have found an easier way. As another user suggested on this post, I made my own custom filter in which I included my own math rules and what they return. So if value >=0 and value <= 0.9, return 'Very Easy', anc so on. Then I had {{ avg_ratings.difficulty_rating__avg|difficulty_readable }} in my template code which took care of the rest. This way my template looks a little cleaner! Thank you for the help once again! This community is incredible

Comment: Yeah custom filter is more cleaner but you will end up writing 4 filters for four different ratings and hard coded choices display, unless you know how to make that more generic. Thanks!